# "to who may have done this" vs. "to whom may have done this"

Tags: formal-language, who-whom

What should I use? Whom or Who in this sentence

> The Noble requests help from anyone with any clues as to **whom** may have done this.

or

> The Noble requests help from anyone with any clues as to **who** may have done this.

Comment: The *thin* line between *who and whom* is vanishing in all English.

Comment: "(The Noble requests help) (from anyone) (with any clues) (as to) (*who* may have done this)." You can see *who* is the subject of it's phrase. But some people may automatically use *whom* after *to*, since *to whom* is commonly used in prepositional phrases.

Answer (score 1):

- "Who may have done this?" - "I/he/she/they/it/we/you did this"

**Who** is the subject in this phrase here.

Comment: * *Who* is the subject of the phrase, but not the subject of the sentence. This is an important distinction.

Answer (score 0):

As a basic rule of thumb *who* is the subject of the verb (the one doing the action) 
*whom* is the object of the verb (the one being acted upon) 
for further reading on who and whom: http://linguistech.ca/Tips+and+Tricks+-+Who+vs.+Whom

Thus, I believe who would be a better fit for this sentence because who is the subject of the verb because they are the ones doing the action.

Answer (score 0):

I think neither Who nor Whom are correct for this sentence.

> The Noble requests help from anyone with any clues as to `anyone who` may have done this.

Or

> The Noble requests help from anyone with any clues as to `whoever` may have done this.

Before who is always a `noun`.